# xamlparseexception was unhandled

Tags: wpf

Cannot create instance of 'Window1' defined in assembly 'WpfApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  Error in markup file 'Window1.xaml' Line 1 Position 9.

how do i solve this issue?

line 1 of my window1.xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jeff, the first line (root) of the `xaml` file should be something like this,

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
```

From [XAML Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx#xaml_root_elements_and_xaml_namespaces)

> The root element also contains the attributes xmlns and xmlns:x. These attributes indicate to a XAML processor which XAML namespaces contain the type definitions for backing types that the markup will reference as elements. The xmlns attribute specifically indicates the default XAML namespace.
>
> Within the default XAML namespace, object elements in the markup can be specified without a prefix. For most WPF application scenarios, and for almost all of the examples given in the WPF sections of the SDK, the default XAML namespace is mapped to the WPF namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation. The xmlns:x attribute indicates an additional XAML namespace, which maps the XAML language namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the `x` namespace that comes included in XAML files by default.  Otherwise it would be invalid.  It seems you did so the parser has no idea what the `x` namespace is referring to.  You should have these lines somewhere within the root:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```